# How does iframe_api Control Mobile (youtube-api)?

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

How does `iframe_api` (script) mobile work?

When `playerVars` equals to 0, I can't play mobile; but when `playerVars` equals to 1 or 2, I can.

```
<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="playerLayer"></div>
</div>
```

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('playerLayer', {
            height: '520',
            width: '560',
            html5 : 0,
            videoId: 'jp2lDKlxFVY',
            playerVars : {
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                wmode: "opaque"
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```